# How to define an anonymous math operator?

Tags: math-operators

I use `DeclareMathOperator` all the time, but it has a side effect and creates a new definition that pollutes my namespace.

So I have a definition like this `\DeclareMathOperator{\case}{case}`, and then when I want to use `case`, I type `\case`.

I'd like to be able to define a function like `op` (e.g. `\op{case}`) and have that behave just like an operator created using `DeclareMathOperator`. For the most part, I currently use `\text{...}` if I'm only using something once or twice, which has the drawback that I have to explicit handle spaces myself.

Is it possible to define something like `\op`?

Comment: `\operatorname{case}`

Comment: You have `\operatorname{case}`, but you shouldn't use operators only to have text in roman. You have `\text` or `\mathrm` for that.